# Interpreting riemann sum as an integral.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I'm trying to figure out if I can interpret this riemann sum

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2n+k}  $$

as

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x \frac{1}{2x+y}dy $$

It seems it is correct because both expression give me the same result, $\ln\dfrac{3}{2}$, but I don't see how to derive the second expression from the first one.

Thanks in advance,

Best regards.

Tom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Write the series as:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2+k/n}$$
now the general trick is to replace $\frac{1}{n}$ with $dx$ and determine the limits of integration, which are:
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{2+x}dx$$
**Edit:**

To imply your integral from that infinite sum, first note that:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_1^x\frac{1}{2x+y}dy=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^n\frac{1}{2n+x}dx$$
Now take a look at the picture in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1926484/301977) to see:
$$\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{2n+k}<\int_1^n\frac{1}{2n+x}dx<\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2n+k}$$
Hence regarding:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{2n+k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{2n+k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2n+k}$$
and the sandwich theorem, proves the statement.

Comment: Yes, I got that expression but I don't see why $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{1}{2+x}dx = \lim_{x \to \infty} \int_1^x \frac{1}{2x+y}dy$. How can I go from the first one to the second?

Comment: That is what I am asking for. The notes I have, says that my second expression of the first post, is derived from the first one, which is confusing me because I don't see how I can derive it.

Comment: @Tom See the edited version of my answer

Comment: Thanks :) Complete answer.