# Why won't a series converge if the limit of the sequence is 0?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Just thinking about it in terms of logic, shouldn't the series of a sequence whose limit as $n$ approaches infinity is 0 converge?

I know that the $n$th term test for divergence says that if a series is convergent, then the limit of its sequence is 0 and I also know there are some sequences for which it has been "proven" that their series does not converge even though the sequence converges to 0, but I just don't believe these tests. If we stretch $n$ out to infinity and the terms are approaching 0, then how is it possible for the sum of the terms to "overflow" and diverge if the terms are becoming negligibly small?

Comment: "but I just don't believe these tests.". Then you should start writing proofs yourself.

Comment: Look forward to local field theory. Over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ these two concepts are indeed equivalent, but unfortunately not over the reals.

Comment: The nature of series many times is not intuitive. Indeed the nature of mathematics is not necessarily intuitive. This is the reason why in the XX cetury the formalism born and become essential to progress in mathematics.

Comment: I wonder what you mean by "I just don't believe these tests". For example, if there is a statement that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n$ does not converge, and if you read a proof for that: what exactly is it that you don't believe?

Comment: Yeah, I know the harmonic series proof, but something about the conclusion just doesn't "click" for me. It seems that it _should_ converge, yet it doesn't

Comment: @AleksandrH if you draw the series $\sum \frac1n$ you will see why it cannot converge. It is the same reason why the function $f(x)=\log x$ is not bounded.

Comment: But it's from n = 1 to infinity, not from n = 0 to infinity. If it were from 0, I could see why it would diverge, since as you approach 0, the terms shoot off to infinity

Comment: @AleksandrH I cant found an image. The function $f(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k, n\in\Bbb N$ can be seen as a finite function represented by rectangles of width $1$.

Comment: Yep, that I know, and it's part of the integral test, and I know why that works.

Comment: It's quite hard to convince someone who will throw away rigorous proof just because it doesn't "click" for him.

Comment: @AleksandrH I managed to [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lbvfl3yvgh) what I wanted :p

Comment: It is counter-intuitive, yes. But the key thing to realize is that a sequence converging to zero is not enough. The sequence has to converge to zero "fast enough" for the series to converge.

Comment: Compare to this junior high school case: "My sister told me that my nephew devoted the rest of the evening to searching for a solution. That’s a strange commitment to make when you’ve just been convinced that no such solution exists." https://medium.com/bright/my-nephew-brought-home-this-menacing-maths-problem-e8bbba30e5cb

Comment: I think the key issue here is in your comment that "It seems that it *should* converge, yet it doesn't." Even though the answers by Henning Makholm and 5xum seem to have solved the present problem for you, you're likely to encounter other situations where your intuition of what *should* happen disagrees with what a proof shows actually *does* happen. In any such situation, you should study the proof carefully in order to correct your intuition. Knowing that your intuition was wrong is a good thing, but improving your intuition is even better.

Comment: I agree with Andreas' comment. The key phrase in your question is the very first words: "just thinking about it in terms of logic" is what you say, but then you go on to say that you wish to reject the rigorous logical conclusions on the basis of an intuition about how things should work. There are many, many counter-to-your-intuition conclusions in mathematics -- particularly in non-finite mathematics! -- and it takes a considerable amount of training to develop an intuition for how it really works. Keep at it!

Comment: @Geliormth But "rigorous" is an ill-defined concept ;)

Comment: The series converges to 0, but never reaches it. All values are positive, and there is an infinite number of them! Isn't it at least equally surprising that some of those sums _do_ converge?

Comment: Also take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926470). You will find some interesting ideas there. (This question might even be a somehow duplicate of that)

Comment: Define "negligibly small"

Answer (score 134, accepted):

A very easy counterexample would be
$$ 1, \underbrace{\frac12, \frac12}_{2\text{ halves}},
\underbrace{\frac13, \frac13, \frac13}_{3\text{ thirds}},
\underbrace{\frac14, \frac14, \frac14, \frac14}_{4\text{ fourths}},
\underbrace{\frac15, \frac15, \frac15, \frac15, \frac15}_{5\text{ fifths}},
\ldots $$
This sequence clearly converges to $0$, but if you try to sum it, it should be obvious that it has partial sums as large as you'd like them to be -- so the series *diverges*.

Try whichever argument you have in mind for believing that the series *should converge*, and attempt to figure out why it doesn't work for this one.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you -- now I don't know whether to select your answer or @5xum 's. Both are very easy to understand. That's an interesting counter example! I never would have thought about it that way :)

Comment: Isn't it (simillar to) part of a proof that $\sum_n^\infty\frac1n$ is divergent?

Comment: @Crowley yes, but it's even more obvious that the sum diverges, at the expense of the series being more complicated to describe

Comment: I have to say this is the most beatiful divergent series I have ever seen. It's much easier to understand than the 1/2^n * 2^n one.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful What about $1+2+3+4+5+\dots=-\frac1{12}$? $\trollface$

Comment: @PyRulez: This is as true as $0=1$.

Comment: @PyRulez It's very annoying that no-one ever seems to give, with that claim, the attendant context _"The zeta-regularized sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}$ equals $\zeta(s)$, the Riemann zeta function. The Riemann zeta function's analytical continuation to $\zeta(-1)$ is $-\frac{1}{12}$"_. Moreover, people conveniently forget that these regularized divergent-series summations are not linear and stable; For instance, adding ***0s*** can completely change the value of the series, as can reordering the terms of their summation.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist wait, how can adding a 0 change the sum? This shouldn't affect the analytical continuation.

Comment: @PyRulez: Zeta-function regularization is not affected by insertion of zeroes; on the other hand it is not _linear_.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Can you recommend an *easy* reading about this? I'm not looking for something accessible to high schoolers, but the most simple reference you know would be helpful for a first reading.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle Sure! I think [this link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/sums-of-divergent-series/) explains well and concisely methods for summing divergent series and the properties they have.

Answer (score 45):

Do you think the series

$$1+\frac12+\frac12 + \frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14 + \frac18 + \cdots$$

converges? Note, there are $2$ terms equal to $\frac12$, $4$ terms equal to $\frac14$, $8$ terms equal to $\frac18$ and so on, with $2^i$ terms equal to $\frac{1}{2^i}$ for each $i\in\mathbb N$.

You will probably agree that this series diverges. In fact, if you give me a number $m\in \mathbb N$, I can calculate exactly how many terms of the series you have to add together for the sum to reach $m$.

For example, it takes $1$ term to reach $1$, it takes $1+2=3$ terms to reach $2$, and then $1+2+4=7$ terms to reach $3$. You can show, with a simple inductive argument, that you will reach $m$ after

$$1+2+4+\dots + 2^{m-1}$$

terms, which is actually equal to $2^m-1$ and is certainly a finite number.

---

It's good to understand the concept why this series diverges. The thing is that yes, the terms go to $0$, but they don't do so "fast enough". The problem is than once the terms hit $\frac14$, they stick at that number for $4$ steps, long enough for the sum to increase by $1$.

And imagine what happens way way way down the line. The sum is equal to $\frac{1}{1024}$ for a whole $1024$ terms, for example. Sure, it will *eventually* fall to an even lower number, but it will stay on that number for *even longer*, again long enough for the whole sum to increase by $1$.

---

Side fact: the series I wrote down at the start has the bonus property that each term in the sequence is larger than the corresponding term of the sequence

$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\cdots$$

which is also known as the *harmonic series* and is the most famous divergent series. So, you now see that if you sum $2^m$ terms of the harmonic series, your sum will be equal to **at least** $m$ (and more, in fact).

Comment: "each term in the sequence is larger..." i think you mean each term of your series is less than or equal to each term in the harmonic series.

Comment: @SteveCox - No. That part is correct. The error is in the statement about the sums of the harmonic series, which will be *less* than this series, not greater.

Comment: @PaulSinclair No, actually Steve Cox was right.

Comment: @5xum. You'd better check again. The 3rd term of your series is $1\over 2$, the third term of the harmonic series is $1\over 3$. ${1\over 2} > {1\over 3}$. For for the 5th, 6th, 7th terms, ${1\over 4} > {1\over 5}, {1\over 6}, {1\over 7}$, etc. Divide the terms in your series by $2$ and it works, but as stated, it does not.

Comment: As an additional sanity check, the sum of the first $n$ terms of the Harmonic series is asymptotically $\ln n$, so the first $2^m$ terms sum to about $m \ln 2$, which is less than $m$ (but more than $m/2$).

Answer (score 16):

However note that in the field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbf Q_p$, a series $\sum_na_n$ converges if and only if the sequence $(a_n)$ tends to $0$.

Comment: When $p^{n\to\infty}\to0$ all bets are off.

Answer (score 12):

I will assume that [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) is believable enough.

While I could relate to you that ratio or root tests are not that easy to understand intuitively, it doesn't get more visual than integral test for convergence. I mean, [look at this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Integral_Test.svg#/media/File:Integral_Test.svg). You can immediately see that $$\int_1^{n+1}\frac{dx}x\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 k$$ Employ Fundamental theorem to get $$\ln(n+1)\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1 k$$ so, harmonic series diverges because logarithm is unbounded. And why is logarithm unbounded? Because it is the inverse of $\exp\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R_+$.

Answer (score 11):

You are echoing a **2-millenia-old** quesite: *will Achilles overtake the Tortoise ?* , and
*if Achilles decelerates,..*. 
Convergence/divergence of infinite sequences and series took long time to be mastered somehow, also because it was clear that the result of adding many small terms was depending on *how many* vs. *how small*.
Just consider *Stereographic Projection* and the philosophical debates it arouses.

Comment: in achilles and the tortoise, the problem is to demonstrate that the series _converges_

Comment: @njzk2 yes, but the *question* posed (and not well-answered by Ancient Greek mathematics) was "how do we correctly handle infinite series"

Comment: Also, this illustrates why we care about rigorous definitions in math. Once we've defined what a sequence is, what convergence means, etc., this isn't a philosophical question; it has a definite answer. (Modulo mapping a question about a race in the real world to one about infinite series, but whatever.)

Comment: @anomaly, yes actually I made a mixture, but I was mainly addressing the philosophical / psychological angst signalled by OP: how can "many" "vanishing" entities add up to infinite

Answer (score 9):

Just look at the problem from the other end.

Take a function like $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ or $\log x$ - they grow infinitely with the $x$ growth, though their growth ratio decreases (their first derivatives tend to zero).

Consider the function increments for equal steps of argument, say, for arguments natural:
$$\Delta f = f(n+1) - f(n)\quad \text{ for } n\in\mathbb N^+$$
As the $f$ function grows slower and slower, these deltas get smaller and smaller for growing $n$, and they actually tend to zero: for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $n$ big enough, for which $\Delta f < \varepsilon$.

Now $\Delta f$ defines a sequence convergent to zero, whose partial sums are values of $\sqrt n$, that is a function growing with no bound, hence a divergent series.